# C# Entity Framework Error: "SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_718"

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm fairly new to using Entity Framework, and cannot figure out this error. I am pulling data from an excel sheet and putting it into a database with EF. There are other posts for this issue, but after going through them, nothing seemed to work.

To finish off my error statement, it says: "The conflict occurred in the database 'DataWarehouse', table 'dbo.RVTools_vSwitch', column 'vSwitch_id'." In following the paper trail on this, I can confirm that there is a column 'vSwitch_id' in the dbo.RVTools_vSwitch table. vSwitch is one of the sheets in my excel file, and the vSwitch_id is automatically made by EF.

When I try to import data from a different excel sheet, vPort, I run into the issue. One of the items that needs to be imported into the database is a vSwitch_id. So I have a GetID function that uses a few parameters given by the excel sheet to find the correct ID, however this still doesn't work.

The next thing I tried was looking through the classes for vPort and vSwitch that contain the EF calls to add data into the database and the migrations to check that everything that was needed was there, but couldn't find any issues there.

So if I have the correct migrations, correct classes, correct data from excel, and I have the correct tables and rows in my database, *what* else could be causing this error?

Here is the code for importing the data from excel to the database. VSwitchId is where the error is and vPort is the sheet I'm importing:

```
foreach (DataRow dataRow in Data.Rows)
            {
                context.RvtoolsVPort.Add(new RvtoolsVPort
                {
                    PortGroup = dataRow[0].ToString(),
                    Vlan = Convert.ToInt32(dataRow[1]),
                    PromiscuousMode = Convert.ToBoolean(bool.Parse(dataRow[2].ToString())),
                    MacChanges = Convert.ToBoolean(bool.Parse(dataRow[3].ToString())),
                    ForgedTransmits = Convert.ToBoolean(bool.Parse(dataRow[4].ToString())),
                    TrafficShaping = Convert.ToBoolean(bool.Parse(dataRow[5].ToString())),
                    Width = Convert.ToInt32(dataRow[6]),
                    Peak = Convert.ToInt32(dataRow[7]),
                    Burst = Convert.ToInt32(dataRow[8]),
                    Policy = dataRow[9].ToString(),
                    ReversePolicy = Convert.ToBoolean(bool.Parse(dataRow[10].ToString())),
                    NotifySwitch = Convert.ToBoolean(bool.Parse(dataRow[11].ToString())),
                    RollingOrder = Convert.ToBoolean(bool.Parse(dataRow[12].ToString())),
                    Offload = Convert.ToBoolean(bool.Parse(dataRow[13].ToString())),
                    Tso = Convert.ToBoolean(bool.Parse(dataRow[14].ToString())),
                    ZeroCopyXmit = Convert.ToBoolean(bool.Parse(dataRow[15].ToString())),
                    VSwitchId = vSwitch.GetID(dataRow[19].ToString(), dataRow[16].ToString(), dataRow[18].ToString(), dataRow[17].ToString(), assessment_id),
                    AssessmentId = assessment_id
                });
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Here is the class for vPort:

```
namespace KelderModel
{
    public partial class RvtoolsVPort
    {
        public int VPortId { get; set; }
        public string PortGroup { get; set; }
        public int? Vlan { get; set; }
        public bool? PromiscuousMode { get; set; }
        public bool? MacChanges { get; set; }
        public bool? ForgedTransmits { get; set; }
        public bool? TrafficShaping { get; set; }
        public int? Width { get; set; }
        public int? Peak { get; set; }
        public int? Burst { get; set; }
        public string Policy { get; set; }
        public bool? ReversePolicy { get; set; }
        public bool? NotifySwitch { get; set; }
        public bool? RollingOrder { get; set; }
        public bool? Offload { get; set; }
        public bool? Tso { get; set; }
        public bool? ZeroCopyXmit { get; set; }
        public int VSwitchId { get; set; }
        public int AssessmentId { get; set; }
        public virtual Assessment Assessment { get; set; }
        public virtual RvtoolsVSwitch VSwitch { get; set; }
       }
 }
```

Finally, here is the code in my migration for vPort:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "RVTools_vPort",
            columns: table => new
            {
                vPort_id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                port_group = table.Column<string>(unicode: false, maxLength: 255, nullable: true),
                vlan = table.Column<int>(nullable: true),
                promiscuous_mode = table.Column<bool>(nullable: true),
                MAC_changes = table.Column<bool>(nullable: true),
                forged_transmits = table.Column<bool>(nullable: true),
                traffic_shaping = table.Column<bool>(nullable: true),
                width = table.Column<int>(nullable: true),
                peak = table.Column<int>(nullable: true),
                burst = table.Column<int>(nullable: true),
                policy = table.Column<string>(unicode: false, maxLength: 255, nullable: true),
                reverse_policy = table.Column<bool>(nullable: true),
                notify_switch = table.Column<bool>(nullable: true),
                rolling_order = table.Column<bool>(nullable: true),
                offload = table.Column<bool>(nullable: true),
                TSO = table.Column<bool>(nullable: true),
                zero_copy_xmit = table.Column<bool>(nullable: true),
                vSwitch_id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                assessment_id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_RVTools_vPort", x => x.vPort_id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_849",
                    column: x => x.assessment_id,
                    principalTable: "Assessment",
                    principalColumn: "assessment_id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_718",
                    column: x => x.vSwitch_id,
                    principalTable: "RVTools_vSwitch",
                    principalColumn: "vSwitch_id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });
```

Could there be some issues in the migration with the constraints? Thank you for any help you might bring.

Comment: Not related to the question but why are you converting a parsed bool to a bool - it seems very redundant `Convert.ToBoolean(bool.Parse(dataRow[3].ToString()))`

Comment: That's a very good point! I didn't even realize that before. I used ctrl + f to replace some casts and that got left there.